# GitLab CI Error Job failed (system failure)

Tags: node.js, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

Anyone has any idea how I can correct this error? Seems templates on GitLab don't work.

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/runner-mh5zgyxe-project-119-concurrent-0-cache-c33bcaa1fd2c77edfc3893b41966cea8/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/19e6d863d0d048b030aa4702ee47667085a8e571c266b9623294c4ac68e7c8da/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/19e6d863d0d048b030aa4702ee47667085a8e571c266b9623294c4ac68e7c8da/merged/builds\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/19e6d863d0d048b030aa4702ee47667085a8e571c266b9623294c4ac68e7c8da/merged/builds: no space left on device\\\"\"": unknown (docker.go:817:0s)
```

Comment: Do you use personal runner?

Comment: What are personal runners?